# Remove duplicate values next to each other - Python List inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to remove duplicate values next to each other, within a list inside a dictionary in python. Give me the best optimized mechanism to achieve this required output.

**sample input**

```
mydir = {
    "p1":[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1],
    "p2":[1,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,0,0]
}
```

**required output**

```
mydir = {
    "p1":[0,1,2,3,2,1],
    "p2":[1,2,1,2,3,0]
}
```

Comment: The dictionary is irrelevant. Figure out how to do it for a single list, then iterate over the dictionary to do it to all the elements.

Comment: You can check out `itertools.groupby`, e.g. `{k: [u for u, _ in groupby(v)] for k, v in mydir.items()}`.

Comment: You can try like `[c for i, c in enumerate(lst) if lst[i-1] !=c]`

Comment: mydir = {
    "p1":[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1],
    "p2":[1,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,0,0]
}
for key,value in  mydir.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
    value = list(set(value))
    mydir[key]=value
    print(value)
print(mydir)